# Push navigation animation without overlapping UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller, segue

I would like to perform a push segue but modify the animation such that the two view controllers don't overlap during the animation, but instead the second view controller "pushes" the first view controller off the screen entirely to the left on a flat plane?

Siri displays this animation when you ask about movies that are playing then tap on one of them, and then again when you tap on Rotten Tomatoes. Notice it fully supports interactive navigation via the swipe back gesture.

[image]

I would like to learn how to replicate this exactly but have no idea where to begin. I am wondering if `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` will come into play here to obtain the custom transition between view controllers? Note that I only need to support iOS 8+ and this segue is defined in the Storyboard.

Comment: UIPageViewController

Comment: @Bluehound Notice in Siri the default animation in the nav bar still occurs with the title and back button, so they're using a push segue not a `UIPageViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be it, if not you can play with the parameters:

```
UIViewController *vc = ...
UINavigationController *currentNavigationController = ...

CATransition* animation = [[[CATransition alloc] init] autorelease];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[animation setDuration:0.5f];
[currentNavigationController.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
[currentNavigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
```

Comment: This kind of works (after changing it to Right). But this causes the backgrounds of the view controllers to change alpha to and from 0. It moves the entire screen over when I would like to keep the default nav bar animations. And when you tap the back button they still overlap during the animation. I need an interactive animation for navigating back, exactly like it works in Siri. :)